# Getting cron to start Redis on reboot

Tags: cron, redis

I am trying to get Redis to start every time my system reboots to make sure that the cache are availables to my webserver. What I did is that inserted the following line in my crontab:

```
@reboot redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
```

After rebooting my system, the cron logs indicate that the cronjob has run:

```
Aug 15 01:10:59 hostname cron[1097]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Aug 15 01:10:59 hostname CRON[1176]: (regis) CMD (redis-server /path/to/redis.conf)
```

However, the redis server is *not* running, and that's my problem. Note that the redis server starts just fine whenever I run the command line in bash.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Cron probably isn't the right tool for this.  A process monitor like Monit would be a better choice, as it will be able to bring redis back up if it falls down when the server is running.  If you're on Ubuntu/Debian, you can use Upstart to keep redis running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by giving the full path to redis-server to cron. The crontab now looks like this:

```
@reboot /usr/local/bin/redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
```

Comment: Strongly recommended to use init scripts for your distribution so that proper start/stop is achieved and is consisted with your OS.